# Calculating upper and lower limits using C++

Tags: c++, limit

I am writing a class that spits out polynomials based on a constants array *a* and exponent array *b*, such that this equation is generated:

[image]

However, this equation does not have a solution for f(0), but it can be calculated using the limits from both sides (given that they are equal). How could you implement this in C++, since I do absolutely not know where to start.

**EDIT**

---

Thanks for the comments (I cannot comment yet). I was indeed a bit too fast with the coding, but I do nevertheless want to write the function myself, because that is exactly the thing I want to learn.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788719/what-is-the-best-approach-to-calculating-function-limits/54859327 might help

Comment: How would you implement this "on paper"? Writing code in a specific language is a secondary step after figuring out how a problem can be solved

Comment: I completely agree with grek40. In the solution I have linked in my earlier comment, they suggest using wolfram-alpha for the calculation. You could basically just call a service of your choice if you want to do it the easy way. Maybe there exists a good c++ math-library for your purpose.

Comment: "a solution for f(0)" -- this is confusing. The function is not defined at 0, is that what you mean?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I mean that it is not defined, but it can be calculated by taking the limits from both sides given that they are equal.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify things, preferably not by appending an "EDIT" section as you did but simply by fixing the question text to clarify it. The question is versioned anyway so older versions remain available. That said, I also don't see a programming question yet. Get falimiliar with C++ and provide an algorithm on paper, then combine the two.

Comment: *"it can be calculated using the limits from both sides (given that they are equal)"* [Well...](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dixoa7diqs)

Comment: Actually I think you don't need a generic solution to the limit values calculation. In your case, you could sum up all `a_i, a_j` values where the corresponding `b_i` is equal `b_j`. Then, if there are any negative `b_i` values remaining with `a_i != 0`, take the lowest `b_i` value (max negative number). It will always be a function that ends in positive and/or negative infinity, depending on, whether the exponent is odd or even

Comment: Are the values in `a` and `b` always whole numbers or could they be fractional?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Obviously the lower limit is -inf and the upper limit is +inf. Are you looking for a way find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the limits for `f(0)` will depend only on the smallest exponent of the normalized polynom.

The normalized polynom (as I call it) is the polynom, where all `a` values, that belong to a repeated `b` value are added up and only the non-zero `a` values are kept.

1. If the smallest exponent is greater than 0, then `f(0) = 0`
2. If the smallest exponent is 0, the corresponding `a` value is the result for `f(0)`
3. If the smallest exponent is smaller than 0, the limits are positive and/or negative infinity

   - Even smallest exponent means the upper and lower limit goes same direction
   - Odd smallest exponent means the upper and lower limit goes opposite direction

This approach only works for whole numbers `b`. At least I didn't investigate all the details for other cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

double f0(int* a, int* b, int n);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {2, 4, 6, -2, 5, -4};
    int b[] = {2, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1};
    // number of values in array a and b
    int n = 6;
    
    double result = f0(a, b, n);
    
    cout << "f(0) = " << result << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

double f0(int* a, int* b, int n)
{
    map<int, int> exponents;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        exponents[b[i]] += a[i];
        // debug printing intermediate sums per exponent
        cout << b[i] << ": " << exponents[b[i]] << endl;
    }
    
    int minExp = 0;
    
    for (auto it = exponents.begin(); it != exponents.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (it->second != 0 && it->first < minExp)
        {
            minExp = it->first;
        }
    }
    
    // no negative exponent. f(0) is defined by 0 exponents
    if (minExp == 0) return exponents[0];
    
    // minimum exponent is even => positive or negative infinity limit
    if (minExp % 2 == 0)
    {
        return exponents[minExp] > 0
            ? numeric_limits<double>::infinity()
            : -numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    }
    
    // minimum exponent is odd => f(0) limits approach both positive AND negative infinity
    return numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

double F(int X)
{
    const int numOfSentence = 3;
    double a[numOfSentence] = { 2,4,6 };
    double b[numOfSentence] = { 1,2,-1 };

    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfSentence; i++)
    {
        result += a[i] * pow(X, b[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << F(2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Rasouli for answering, but this was not really my question. My question is how one should go about computing undefined numbers. In this scenario that would be calculating `f(0)`.